# Eclipse/Papyrus - "The import org.eclipse.papyrus cannot be resolved" when trying to create diagrams from text input (ModelSet implementation)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, xtext, papyrus

I'm trying to generate UML Diagrams from a specification written in a DSL created using Xtext. To this end, I installed Papyrus on my Eclipse IDE and have an handler that extracts and processes the information from the ".mydsl" file.

So, I read about the ModelSet class and how it can be used to create Papyrus models somewhat automatically. The issue is that I can't seem to use it, since any import of "org.eclipse.papyrus" cannot be resolved. Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to find the solution, if anyone cares.

Just add the missing imports to the Dependencies tab in your plugin.xml.

Cheers!